# Is there a “non-religious” definition of “catholique”?

Tags: adjectifs, sens, religion

In one of my favorite songs by [Gilbert Becaud](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_B%C3%A9caud), “[L'homme et la Musique](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7nz7k_l-homme-et-la-musique-de-becaud-cha_music)” there is a passage I don't understand:

> Breve, nous ne sommes,
>   Pas des amants catholiques.

I'm confused by the world “catholique”. It's usually a religious reference, but it doesn't seem to be so in this case.

Is there another common meaning that I'm missing?

Comment: Attention que, d'après http://paroles.zouker.com/gilbert-becaud/l-homme-et-la-musique,159819.htm ou http://www.frmusique.ru/texts/b/becaud_gilbert/hommeetlamusique.htm ce n'est pas _Breve, nous ne sommes_ mais _**Bref**, nous ne sommes_. Qui a raison ?...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sometimes `catholique` is used to refer to something that is "the norm", what all people do usually.

"Ce gâteau ne me semble pas très catholique" means that you find the cake does not fit the standards for being called a cake: because it is weird looking, or tasting strange or whatever.

This meaning comes from the history of France to have a majority of Catholics since a long time. (I guess)

Comment: OK, so it means, "We're not the USUAL kind of lovers." That makes sense in this context. Another word I might use in this context is "orthodox."

Comment: "orthodoxe" is also used the same way, and I think that's the same in English; basically it means "strict" in this context. "Plus catholique que le pape" = as strict as one can be

Comment: @Joubarc: regarding "orthodox[e]": "strict" *is* the very definition of the word... and the reason it was used for the eponymous branch of christianity... (to be fair, "catholic"/"catholique" also does literally mean "universal", but I doubt it is the reason why the word is used to mean "in the norm")

Comment: This answer is misleading without mentioning that it's mostly used to refer to *moral norm*. In this case, it isn't about "the usual kind of lovers" but rather "lovers who do naughty things." It's a reference to their sex life, not simply about how unorthodox they are.

Comment: A mildly equivalent English word could be 'kosher' (at least for the cake, not sure about the lovers!)

Comment: @Dave Sorry for the annoyance, but you misused *eponymous*. The word *orthodox* is eponymous of the branch of christianity, not the other way.

Comment: @Borror0: Although in this specific case you're probably right about the "nasty things" (admitting you can be both "amant" and "catholique" anyway, which I doubt...), I don't agree this expression is mostly about moral norm. On the contrary : when talking about moral norm, there could then be a confusion with the catholic moral norm. At least when talking about obviously non-religious context, "pas très catholique" doesn't convey any religious meaning.

Answer (score 8):

*Catholique* can, by association with the church by that name, often mean "moral" or "correct", hence the common expression *Ce n'est pas catholique!* Thus the lyrics of this song probably mean that they are "immoral" (i.e., not chaste) lovers.

Comment: Except that they were "L'Homme, et La Musique," Therefore, "abnormal" is fine in this context, "unchaste" (or impudique) is not.

Comment: The sexual connotation of *pas catholique* does not exist everywhere. We had a [short chat about this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=1672013#1672013). It seems to be obvious in Quebec and to exist in some regions of France but not all. I (mostly Parisian) had never heard of it until now.

Comment: *Ce n'est pas **très** catholique!* plutôt (sans très c'est ambigu)